# JOIN two tables, sort by field on second table, no duplicates

Tags: mysql

My apologies but I cannot get my head around this one (even not after searching and trying out a few things). All I want to do is join two tables and then sort the join descending on the created_at in the article_translations table. However, I need unique entries.

I have two tables:

```
articles
--------
id
user_id
```

```
article_translations
--------
id
article_id (brings this table together with the other one)
locale
title
...
created_at
updated_at
```

Performing mysql query:

```
SELECT * from articles
JOIN article_translations as t on t.article_id = articles.id 
ORDER BY t.created_at desc
```

I get the joined tables with the corresponding related entries.

```
articles.id t.article_id created_at
1               1           ''
1               1           ''
2               2           ''
```

When I try no to get rid of the duplicates, in this case of the article with id = 1, I get a nasty error:

Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'blog.t.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

The Desired result would be:

```
articles.id t.article_id created_at
1               1           ''
2               2           ''
```

Any help please... Thank You!

Comment: Going on the sample data you did show us, which `created_at` value of the two duplicated do you want to keep?

Comment: In other words, even though an article might have multiple translations you only want the most recent one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get unique rows is if you want the latest (or the earliest?) date for each `id`, which you can do if you `group by a.id, t.article_id` and aggregate:

```
SELECT a.id, t.article_id, MAX(t.created_at) AS created_at 
FROM articles AS a INNER JOIN article_translations AS t 
ON t.article_id = a.id 
GROUP BY a.id, t.article_id
ORDER BY MAX(t.created_at) DESC
```

If you want all the columns of the 2 tables, first get unique rows from `article_translations` with `NOT EXISTS` and then join to `articles`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM articles AS a INNER JOIN (
  SELECT t.*
  FROM article_translations t
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM article_translations
    WHERE article_id = t.article_id AND created_at > t.created_at
  )
) AS t 
ON t.article_id = a.id 
ORDER BY t.created_at DESC
```

This will work if there are not more than 1 rows in `article_translations` with the same maximum `created_at` for an `article_id`.
For MySql 8.0+ you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY t.created_at DESC) rn 
  FROM articles AS a INNER JOIN article_translations AS t 
  ON t.article_id = a.id 
) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to get the earlierst/latest article, so MAX() would be correct. I also came to this solution when I excluded the Join and played around with the article_translations only.

Comment: If you don't really need any columns from `articles` then the join is not necessary.

Comment: And just to understand this whole thing.... Is it correct that the MAX() is needed on the created_at otherwise mysql does not know how to "group" the result further, right? If I do the query without I see that for the id I get for instance two entries for the id 2 with two different dates. So basically I need to tell mysql to take from these remaining ones the one with the "hightest"/max date - yes?

Comment: right, the reason why I did it that way is that I wanted to use the Eloquent Model from Laravel in combination with the Eager Loding option, I wanted to still have access to the Eloquent methods.

Comment: MAX() is needed to perform aggregation on the chosen group and return a single value. In any other case, even with not exists, if there are 2 rows for a group with the same max created_at, 2 rows with that max created_at will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do want *all* the columns:

If you are trying to keep just the article translation with the latest creation date, then assuming the creation dates are unique for a give article's translations, one way would be to create a subquery that computes for each `article_translation.article_id` the maximum `article_translation.created_at` column value:

```
SELECT articles.*, t.* from articles
JOIN article_translations as t on t.article_id = articles.id
JOIN (
   SELECT article_id, max(created_at) as created_at from article_translations
   GROUP BY article_id
) a_t on t.article_id = a_t.article_id and t.created_at = a_t.created_at
ORDER BY t.created_at desc
```

If the creation dates are not unique, or even if they are, then this should also work:

```
SELECT articles.*, t.* from articles
JOIN article_translations as t on t.article_id = articles.id
AND t.article_id = (
    SELECT t2.article_id from article_translations t2
    WHERE t2.article_id = t.article_id
    ORDER BY created_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY t.created_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there with the query in the question. You just need to add the distinct keyword:

```
SELECT distinct * from articles
JOIN article_translations as t on t.article_id = articles.id 
ORDER BY t.created_at desc`
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks forpas for providing the correct answer. I needed this query basically for a Laravel Eloquent model in combination with eager loading. In case anybody cares, that's how the final solution now looks like:

```
$articles = Article::join('article_translations as at', function ($join) {
                            $join->on('articles.id', '=', 'at.article_id');
                    })
                    ->select('articles.id', 
                    'articles.user_id',DB::raw('MAX(at.created_at) as created_at'))
                    ->groupBy('at.article_id')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->with('translations')
                    ->get();
```

Pure SQL

```
SELECT at.article_id, MAX(at.created_at) as created_at FROM articles as a
INNER JOIN article_translations as at
ON a.id = at.article_id
GROUP BY at.article_id
ORDER BY MAX(created_at) desc
```